# Outlook count incoming emails

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I need a way to get a daily count incoming emails into the INBOX before they get filed into sub-folders. Other than manually counting them, is there a known automated solution?

Comment: Do you want to count messages by date, time or category?

Comment: I want a count of incoming emails by date.

Comment: Use code that adds a running count to a text file. Start with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053654/extracting-specific-information-from-outlook-2003-to-excel-using-vba/19596889#19596889

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count the number of email received by following the steps given in this link :

http://www.outlook-tips.net/tips/count-total-number-messages-received-today/.

These links can also be useful :

1)http://email.about.com/od/outlooktips/qt/See_Total_Not_Just_Unread_Inbox_Message_Count_in_Outlook.htm

2) http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/count-received-emails/

Comment: Kindly consider posting some code to support your answer. Link-only answers are frowned upon because they are subject to link rot. Thx

Answer (score 0):

In the search field type "received:today"
The count of items will appear in the bottom left corner.

[image]

[image]